# Lightbox CSS conflict

Tags: css, lightbox, navigationbar

I had lightbox on my site and it was working fine.  I updated the pages with Dreamweaver CS6 to a Fluid grid with a side navigation bar so the site would be more mobile friendly.  The result is that my lightbox images are distorted  and the frame is missing from one side.  When scrolling through the images they will increase in size by a fraction and distortion will lessen.  I figure there is a CSS conflict and I can't figure it out.  Web page is located here,

http://www.crawfordcountyhistoricalsociety.org/Pages/Indians.html

Answer (score 0):

U should remove this style, max-width:100% and padding: 10px.

[image]

Comment: Well that works in IE but not Chrome.  When I preview from dreamweaver in chrome it works but when I upload the page it does not.  I may not have done everything correctly, new to this.